# two definitions of the nerve of a category

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, simplicial-stuff

In Paul Goerss and John Jardine's book on [simplicial homotopy theory they define](https://books.google.com/books?id=iFv2BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false)

the nerve $BC$ of a category $C$ as simplicial set determined by $BC([n])=hom_{cat}([n],C)$.

They then say in other words an $n$- simplex (by definition an element of $hom_{cat}([n],C)$) is a string of composable arrows of length $n$ in $C$.

I don't thing these are equivalent because there are more strings of composable arrows than there are elements in the hom-set:

Take for instance $C=\mathbb{Z}/5$ where $\mathbb{Z}/5$ is the category with one object and one morphism for each element in the group $\mathbb{Z}/5$.  Every functor $F$ from the category $[n]$ to the category $\mathbb{Z}/5$ is determined by what $F(0\leq 1 \leq 2... \leq n)$ is.  $F(0 \leq 1 \leq 2 ... \leq n )$ can be one of $5$ different arrows in the category $\mathbb{Z}/5$.  Therefore there are $5$ different elements in $hom_{cat}([n], \mathbb{Z}/5)$.

The number of composable arrows of length $n$ is $5^n$.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Every functor $F$ from the category $[n]$ to the category $\mathbb{Z}/5$ is determined by what $F(0\leq 1 \leq 2... \leq n)$ is

This is not true.  The morphism $0\leq n$ is just one morphism in the category $[n]$, which does not generate the entire category (if $n>1$).  For instance, knowing what $F(0\leq n)$ is does not determine what $F(0\leq 1)$ is.

Knowing where $F$ sends the entire diagram $0\leq 1\leq 2\leq\dots\leq n$ does determine $F$, but that diagram does not consist of just a single map: it has a map $0\to 1$, a map $1\to 2$, and so on.  These are exactly a string of $n$ composable arrows, and so give a bijection between such functors $F$ and strings of $n$ composable arrows.

Comment: Isn't $0 \leq 1 \leq 2 ...\leq n$ is a morphism between the objects $0$ and $n$ in $[n]$?

Comment: If you compose all those morphisms together, you get a single morphism from $0$ to $n$.  But when I say "the entire diagram", I mean not just that single morphism but each of the individual morphisms $0\leq 1$, $1\leq 2$, and so on.

Comment: First, thanks for spending the time clearing my misconceptions.  I do appreciate it.
 
My understanding was that the morphisms of $[n]$  were mutually distinct paths like $0 \leq 1$, $n-1 \leq n$, $0 \leq n$, $0 \leq 1 ....\leq n$ that are not determined by what their starting and ending points are.   In other words, your 'diagram' is viewed itself as a morphism in the category $[n]$.  Do you have a different definition?

Comment: For each pair of integers $i$ and $j$ such that $0\leq i\leq j\leq n$, there is a unique morphism $i\to j$ in $[n]$.  You can call this morphism whatever you want; if you want to write it as $i\leq i+1\leq\dots\leq j$ that's fine.  But in any case, it is not true that the unique morphism $0\to n$ generates the entire category.

Comment: It seems that you are doing the following:
Define the morphisms of $[n]$ to be arrows $i \to j$ such that $0 \leq i\leq j \leq n$.  Functors on $[n]$ are entirely determined by what they do on $0 \to 1$, $1 \to 2$... $n-1 \to n$.  One develops the theory by saying that $d^i$ is the functor such that $d^i(i-1 \to i)= i-1 \to i+1$, and similarly for $s^i$.

Comment: Now it is clear that $Hom([n], \mathbb{Z}/5)$ is in correspondence with a set of cardinality  the number of ways of distributing $n$ pieces of gold to $5$ pirates.  To be satisfied, I still need to see if the realization of this simplicial set with these $n-$ simplices for $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is the milnor space model of $B(\mathbb{Z}/2)$.